# Download a .gz file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blob

I have to call a remote service to download a gzipped file (csv.gz).
I have to use jQuery because I have to set the Authentication HTTP header.
I tried with something like this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url
            }).done(function (res) {
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.style = 'display: none';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                const blob = new Blob([res]);
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = _this.attributes.id + '.' + _DEFAULT_DOWNLOADED_FILE_EXTENTION;
                a.click();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }).fail(function (err) { });
```

I'm able to download the file but, after the download, I tried to unzip it on my pc but the file is not correct (corrupted). Probably the Blob creation that I used it's not correct.

Comment: Binary data is sent as `Content-type: application/octet-stream`. You might have to state that, either in the jQuery request or when creating the Blob.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to download binary data, you can fetch it using typed arrays in JavaScript, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)'s an example in the MDN.

In regards to setting the Authentication header, you don't need jQuery for that. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader)'s the XHR API that enables you to do it.